# Water marks on my TV

Tags: cleaning, technology

My TV, a 65" Samsung HD 7 series has dripping watermarks on it. How will I fix it? Please help. I tried cleaning with alcohol but the drops are still there.

Comment: Can you take  a picture of the watermarks on the device?

Comment: Follow the [manufacturer's advice](https://www.samsung.com/levant/support/tv-audio-video/samsung-tv-how-should-i-clean-my-tv-screen/). *Never use ...  alcohol ... abrasive pads or paper towels ...* but obtain a screen cleaning solution and use the type of cloth stated.

Comment: I suspect the marks may be on the inside of the screen. Ever since I put my iPhone through the washer it has a lovely "clouds" sort of effect on the screen, most visible when a pure white screen shows. It's apparently water trapped in the sandwich of the screen assembly